# Assignment of struct to an array working in devlopment but not on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, heroku, struct

Ruby on rails application working in development but crashes in Heroku.  In the application I put values in a struct (Selection) which I then load to an array (@selections) for a drop down window selection on the screen.  I have found the line causing this error, see print statements in rails code and on Heroku log, but don't know how to fix it.  Have tried a number of alternatives but so far no luck.  As I specify a version of ruby in my gemfile (ruby  '1.9.3') my understanding is that Heroku would use this version of Ruby (e.g error not caused by different versions of Ruby).

any help appreciated
thanks
Pierre

The Drill controller

```
Selection = Struct.new(:id, :name, :table_index, :user_valuation)

class DrillsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :current_user
  before_filter :load_drill, except: [:index, :new, :create]
  …..
  def load_evaluation_assumption_selections
    load_stake
    @selections = []
    list_of_companies = []
    index = 0   
    @resource_estimations = @drill.resource_estimations
    if @resource_estimations.present?
      @resource_estimations.each do |u|
        unless list_of_companies.include?(u.company_id)
          list_of_companies.push(u.company_id)
          if u.company_id == @stake.company_id
            company_name = "default"
          else
            company_name = u.company.name
          end
          puts "ZZZZZ - before load struct, Selection, to array @selections"
          @selections += [Selection.new(index, company_name, u.id, false)] 
          puts "ZZZZZ - after load struct, Selection,  to array @selections"          
          index += 1
        end
      end
    end
```

Heroku log

```
2013-10-17T05:18:23.714529+00:00 app[web.2]:   Rendered stakes/_drill_interests.html.erb (3.3ms)
2013-10-17T05:18:23.714529+00:00 app[web.2]:   Rendered stakes/_form.html.erb (21.0ms)
2013-10-17T05:18:23.714529+00:00 app[web.2]:   Rendered resource_estimations/_edit_multiple.html.erb (19.5ms)
2013-10-17T05:18:23.714529+00:00 app[web.2]:   Rendered drills/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (72.2ms)
2013-10-17T05:18:23.721851+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/drills/9/edit host=quiet-fortress-3338.herokuapp.com    fwd="203.45.50.22" dyno=web.2 connect=1ms service=102ms status=304 bytes=0
2013-10-17T05:18:23.714529+00:00 app[web.2]: Completed 200 OK in 92ms (Views: 65.6ms | ActiveRecord: 15.4ms)
2013-10-17T05:18:26.140463+00:00 app[web.2]: Started GET "/drills/9/investor" for 203.45.50.22 at 2013-10-17 05:18:26 +0000
2013-10-17T05:18:26.169417+00:00 app[web.2]: ZZZZZ - before load struct, Selection, to array @selections
2013-10-17T05:18:26.173260+00:00 app[web.2]: 
2013-10-17T05:18:26.173260+00:00 app[web.2]: ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (4 for 1)):
2013-10-17T05:18:26.173260+00:00 app[web.2]:   app/controllers/drills_controller.rb:232:in `new'
2013-10-17T05:18:26.173260+00:00 app[web.2]:   app/controllers/drills_controller.rb:232:in `block in load_evaluation_assumption_selections'
2013-10-17T05:18:26.173260+00:00 app[web.2]:   app/controllers/drills_controller.rb:223:in `load_evaluation_assumption_selections'
2013-10-17T05:18:26.173260+00:00 app[web.2]:   app/controllers/drills_controller.rb:59:in `investor'
2013-10-17T05:18:26.173260+00:00 app[web.2]: 
2013-10-17T05:18:26.173260+00:00 app[web.2]: 
2013-10-17T05:18:26.174044+00:00 app[web.2]: Processing by DrillsController#investor as HTML
2013-10-17T05:18:26.174044+00:00 app[web.2]:   Parameters: {"id"=>"9"}
2013-10-17T05:18:26.174044+00:00 app[web.2]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 23ms
2013-10-17T05:18:26.171782+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/drills/9/investor host=quiet-fortress-3338.herokuapp.com fwd="203.45.50.22" dyno=web.2 connect=1ms service=37ms status=500 bytes=643
```

Comment: I have also tried using the ruby "@selections.push(Selection.new(index, company_name, u.id, false))" which I checked as good using IRB, but this dones't work in Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up trying to use a struct for the menu selection options and used a Hash instead.
Pierre